# PHP how to stop the code when a called method use return

Tags: php

I have made a main method which calls a validation method to check if everything is correct. But when the validation method find a problem and want to return the error and show it to the user the main method will continue with the rest of the code. How could you prevent this from happening? Here is my current code:

```
public function postUpdateSettings(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateSettings($request);

        $this->updateSettings($request);

        return redirect()->back()->with('succes', 'Your settings has been changed!');
    }

private function validateSettings(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.Auth::user()->id.'',
            'first_name' => 'required|string|max:50|alpha',
            'insertion' => 'nullable|max:25|alpha_spaces',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|max:50|alpha',
            'job' => 'required',
            'message' => 'nullable|max:500',
        ]);

        $jobs = $this->getJob();
        if(in_array($request->input('job'), $jobs) === false){
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Exception handling in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: you saying cz of this it redirects -if(in_array($request->input('job'), $jobs) === false){
            return redirect()->route('home');
        } ??

Comment: `$this->validateSettings($request);` - you don't do anything with the result of this. But really the validateSettings method should just return an object which indicates success/failure of the validation, and also contains any validation error messages generated. Then the controller method should decide where to route the user (e.g. to redirect them, or whatever). Essentially, currently, you're ignoring the result of the validation method, and arguably the validation method is taking responsibility for something (redirection) which is the job of the controller.

Comment: When that wants to return back to the home page it will continue with the rest of the code in the main method, but I want that it ends there also with the postUpdateSettings method

Comment: Yes, you said that in the question. Did you understand my comment? I have explained what you need to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: Yeah did solve it with replacing return the route with a true or false and did a check with that in the main method